# If I change the _pdpstep and heartbeat the RRD not updated properly

Tags: perl, perl-module, rrdtool, rrd

I have rrd file "abcd" with _pdpstep = 300 and heartbeat = 700. If this is the configuration then it works fine means accept value. But If I create this file newly with _pdpstep = 1200 and heartbeat = 1500 then it gives all value as Nan. How Can I check what is wrong. If you require I can send rrdtool info for both files.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to answer your question.

However, you should probably look at the [documentation](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html)

Specifically the bit about heartbeat, step and the 'xff' in your RRA definitions.

> xff The xfiles factor defines what part of a consolidation interval may be made up from *UNKNOWN* data while the consolidated value is still regarded as known. It is given as the ratio of allowed *UNKNOWN* PDPs to the number of PDPs in the interval. Thus, it ranges from 0 to 1 (exclusive).

It's quite likely that if you're using a different heartbeat, then your sampling interval is now too low.

> The "heartbeat" defines the maximum acceptable interval between samples/updates. If the interval between samples is less than "heartbeat", then an average rate is calculated and applied for that interval. If the interval between samples is longer than "heartbeat", then that entire interval is considered "unknown". Note that there are other things that can make a sample interval "unknown", such as the rate exceeding limits, or a sample that was explicitly marked as unknown.

So, short answer is - if you chance your RRA definition to have a lower xff, then you should stop getting NaNs in your data.

Comment: '-s',
1200,
'DS:p0be:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p1ef:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p2af:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p3nc:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p4bu:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p5bu:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'DS:p6bu:DERIVE:1500:U:U',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:507',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:900',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:6:600',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:72:731',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:1:900',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:6:600',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:72:731'

Comment: '-s',
300,
'DS:p0be:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p1ef:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p2af:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p3nc:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p4bu:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p5bu:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'DS:p6bu:DERIVE:700:U:U',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:507',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:900',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:6:600',
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:72:731',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:1:900',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:6:600',
'RRA:MAX:0.5:72:731'